# Find the limit in distribution of $Z_n=\frac{1}{n}\cdot X+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X,Y$ be random variables and for each $n\in \Bbb{N}$ we define $Z_n=\frac{1}{n}\cdot X+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot Y$ Find the limit in distribution of $Z_n$.

So there is no information about $X$ nor $Y$ and I am basically stucked in

$$\Bbb{P}(Z_n \leq z)=\Bbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot X+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot Y \leq z\right)$$

And I don't know how to proceed since I've got two variables bothering around. Can anyone just give me a HINT? (Just a Hint please)

Comment: It's not a crazy thing to guess that $Z \to Y$ in distribution. Maybe having that as a conceptual target may help a proof outline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Slutsky theorem as follows:

> If $X_n \Rightarrow c$, $Y_n \Rightarrow Y$, where $c$ is a constant, then $X_n + Y_n \Rightarrow Y + c$.

In this question, take $Y_n = \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)Y$ and $X_n = \frac{1}{n}X$.